# How to insert custom text in place of figure

Tags: floats, draft

I would like to replace some figures in a document with a black frame of the same size as the figure, such as that which you get when using `\includegraphics` in draft mode. However, this places the name of the figure file inside the framed box. Is there a way to replace this text with centered text stating 
*Figure removed due to copyright restrictions*?

Answer (score 7):

A suggestion can be the combination of `collectbox`, `adjustbox` and `tikz`.

I tried to avoid TikZ but I wasn't able to create the red rectangle with `adjustbox`.

The code provides two things:

1. A switch do print the image or the copyright information. You can choose by
   `\copyrightimagefalse` or `\copyrightimagetrue`.
2. Instead of using `includegraphics` you must use `\copyrightimage` to work with the previous switch.

[image]

The Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% or load ’graphicx’ and ’blindtext’ manually
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{collectbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifcopyrightimage
\copyrightimagefalse
\newcommand*\copyrightimage[2][]{%
\collectbox{%
  \ifcopyrightimage
  \tikz[outer sep=0pt]\node[fill=red!20,minimum height=\totalheight,minimum width=\width]{%
       \smash{\parbox{\width}{\centering\large\bfseries Figure removed due to copyright restrictions}}
   };%
  \else
     \BOXCONTENT
\fi%
  }{\adjincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\copyrightimage[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{set \texttt{\string\copyrightimagefalse}}
\end{figure}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\copyrightimagetrue
\copyrightimage[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{set \texttt{\string\copyrightimagetrue}}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I cannot seem to get this code working, even if I simply copy-and-paste it and change only the image file. pdfLatex keeps on complaining that \copyrightimage is an undefined control sequence: `Undefined control sequence.
\\copyrightimage ...ENT \fi }{\adjincludegraphics 
                                                  [#1]{#2}}
￼l.24 \copyrightimage[width=0.48\linewidth]{dice}
                                                
?` Could you please confirm if the code works as is? Thanks again...

Comment: @Miguel: Please make an update of your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks - the code now runs! But the box is too wide and shifted to the right (lies outside of the text margins when the image has `width = \textwidth`). Compare: `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[draft, width=\textwidth]{some-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext` versus `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\copyrightimagetrue
\copyrightimage[width=\textwidth]{some-image}
\end{figure}
\blindtext`

Comment: @miguel I will test it later and change the example.

Comment: @Miguel: You use `\includegraphics` instead of `\copyrightimage`. As I wrote I defined a new command instead of redefining `includegraphics`

Comment: No, I was only comparing the box I get with `\includegraphics[draft]` to that which I get with your custom command `\copyrightimage`. Even in your example above, the red box (labelled Figure 2) is wider and located further to the right than your first box (with the A in it labelled as Figure 1).