# Follow up question: How to insert custom text in place of figure - Alignment of replacement box

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, copyright

This question is a follow up for the question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56609/93064

The aim is to replace a figure with a box containing relevant text (e.g. Figure removed for copyright reasons).  The box must be exactly the same size and position as the original figure, to maintain page numbers etc. compared with the full document which contains figures.

The code suggested by Marco Daniel does ALMOST exactly what I need (see below, amended slightly for colour and font):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifcopyrightimage
\copyrightimagefalse
\newcommand*\copyrightimage[2][]{%
\collectbox{%
  \ifcopyrightimage
  \tikz[outer sep=0pt]\node[fill=gray!20,minimum height=\totalheight,minimum width=\width]{%
       \smash{\parbox{\width}{\centering Figure removed from the electronic copy of this thesis due to copyright restrictions}}
   };%
  \else
     \BOXCONTENT
\fi%
  }{\adjincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

In the document...

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering\copyrightimagetrue
\copyrightimage[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

where

```
\copyrightimagetrue \copyrightimage
```

replaces

```
\includegraphics
```

However, as noted by Miguel, the replacement box is actually slightly wider than the original and is shifted slightly to the right.  This means it extends into my page margin for figures which are nearly as wide as the page.

Having not used tikz before, I am struggling to work out where to make amendments to try to solve the problem.

Many thanks in advance.

MWE (please excuse the clumsy code):

```
\RequirePackage[pagewise]{lineno} 
\documentclass[british, a4paper, twoside, 12pt,openright]{report}
\RequirePackage[ignoreall, a4paper, margin=25mm, bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{review_emph_etal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % allows to use \textsubscript
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifcopyrightimage
\copyrightimagefalse
\newcommand*\copyrightimage[2][]{%
\collectbox{%
\ifcopyrightimage
\tikz[outer sep=0pt]\node[fill=gray!20,minimum height=\totalheight,minimum width=\width]{%
   \smash{\parbox{\width}{\centering Figure removed from the electronic copy of this thesis due to copyright restrictions}}%
};%
  \else%
 \BOXCONTENT%
\fi%
}{\adjincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

This is the normal figure:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering 
\includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{FigureFilename}
 \caption{Caption}
 \label{Label}
\end{figure}

This figure is supposed to be a greyed-out version of the one above, with the same positioning and width.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering \copyrightimagetrue
\copyrightimage[width=1.00\textwidth]{FigureFilename}
 \caption{Caption}
 \label{Label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good idea, but adding `%` wherever it seems possible doesn't seem to change the result.  I will try to add a MWE (although I am not 100% sure which of the many packages does what so apologies if more than necessary are included).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

It is presumed that the image file exists (and has a particular dimension) and the aim is to produce either a space or a placeholder that would be the same size as would be produced, while at the same time not making the image available to the reader (could also reduce file size in a draft). You could do something like the below, measuring the image and then inserting a tikz node in its place. By altering the code you could remove or alter the text inside, and remove the border at various times.

I did this by defining a variant of \includegraphics (\includegraphicsd)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\abimagebox
\NewDocumentCommand \includegraphicsd { O{} m }{%
  \sbox\abimagebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      draw,
      dashed,
      text width=\the\dimexpr\wd\abimagebox-.4pt\relax,
      minimum height=\the\dimexpr\ht\abimagebox-.4pt\relax,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0,
    ]{This is white};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

%This image is shown
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.345\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Close up of an opossum, part of the genus of piglet.}
\end{figure}

%This one is not shown
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphicsd[width=0.345\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Close up of an opossum, part of the genus of piglet.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, that does exactly what I needed.  Many thanks.

Comment: I fixed two issues in your code: it should be `\NewDocumentCommand` (minor) and the arguments should be `O{}m` or the absence of the optional command would pass `-NoValue-` as `#1` (this was a major issue).

Comment: There's another issue: the fake image is 0.4pt wider and 0.4pt higher than the non faked one. This is because the dashed rules are drawn “half in and half out”. I fixed it.

Comment: Many thanks for the edits egreg - all good